# JAX-WS - a: prefix in XML tag for Lists

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws, jax-ws-customization

we are upgrading webservices from Java 6 to Java 8 and from JAX-RS to JAX-WS.

After the code upgrade, we noticed that the responses changes when the object involved is a List.

Old responses are like this:

```
<ListObject>
<item></item>
<item></item>
```

New responses are:

```
<a:ListObject>
<item></item>
<item></item>
```

we have an 'a:' prefix before the tag name when the object is a List.

I don't have many experience on JAX-WS. Is it possible to remove the 'a:' prefix in order to not change the responses?

Thanks

Comment: FWIW, moving from JAX-RS to JAX-WS is rather an major architectural change than an upgrade. And you should have an solid understanding of XML Namespaces (and consider the complete responses and their namespace declarations).

Comment: Do you have an xsd schema that has definitions for namespaces?  Maybe look into your xsd schema for this XML first.

Comment: We don't have the XSD schemas, the definitions are inside the WSDL classes